# ACF repeater get specific row by name

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, repeater, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using ACF repeater and i'm trying to list only the files from Relco Components which you can see highlighted in the picture. How can i get only the specific row?

[image]
[image]

```
 <?php if( have_rows('categorie_documentatie', 8) ): ?>

            <?php while( have_rows('categorie_documentatie', 8) ): the_row(); 
              // vars
              echo $nume_categorie_doc     = get_sub_field('nume_categorie_doc');
            ?>
            <?php if( have_rows('subcategorie_doc') ): ?>

                <?php while( have_rows('subcategorie_doc') ): the_row(); 
                  // vars
                  echo $nume_subcategorie_doc     = get_sub_field('nume_subcategorie_doc');
                  $imagine_resursa  = get_sub_field('imagine_resursa');

                ?>

                <?php if( have_rows('fisier_doc') ): ?>

                    <?php while( have_rows('fisier_doc') ): the_row(); 
                      // vars
                      $nume_fisier_doc = get_sub_field('nume_fisier_doc');
                      $file           = get_sub_field('file');
                    ?>

                    <?php if ($nume_subcategorie_doc='Relco Components'): ?>
                      <a href="<?php echo $file; ?>" target="_blank">
                      <h5><?php echo $nume_fisier_doc; ?></h5>
                    </a>
                    <?php endif ?>



                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
                  <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

      <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

  <?php endif; ?>
```

Nothing is failing in the code, i just want to get the field nume_fisier_doc just from the "Relco Components" subcategory.

Comment: Do you know which part of your code is failing e.g. is it meeting the `if( have_rows('fisier_doc') )` condition etc? Have you tried debugging it by echoing a message at each step to work out where its going wrong e.g. `if( have_rows('fisier_doc') ): echo "<p>have_rows('fisier_doc')";` etc. Can you also show how your ACF repeater is set up so we can see what the field names are actually corresponding to in your example?

Comment: The code currently outputs the files from all the subcategories. It even passes the condition:
<?php if ($nume_subcategorie_doc='Relco Components'): ?>
         <a href="<?php echo $file; ?>" target="_blank">
               <h5><?php echo $nume_fisier_doc; ?></h5>
         </a>
<?php endif ?>
Nothing is failing in the code, i just want to get the field nume_fisier_doc just from the "Relco Components" subcategory. I also added how the repeater is set up.

Comment: If nothing's failing in the code, then we know the problem must be with the code looking for the name itself, i.e. `if ($nume_subcategorie_doc='Relco Components'): `, and now that I knew where to look I can see a problem straight away - you are using `=` (assigning the value) instead of `==` (which compares the value). Fix that and see what happens then.

Comment: This was a really stupid mistake lol. You are right, the problem was me using a single = . Everything works fine now. Thanks for the help!